# Testing Controller with Spring-security

Tags: spring-security, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

In the **`OpenApi30Config`** configuration file  I have:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.SecuritySchemeType;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityScheme;

@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "Users API", version = "2.0", description = "Users Information"))
@SecurityScheme(name = "bearerAuth", type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP, bearerFormat = "JWT", scheme = "bearer")
public class OpenApi30Config {

}
```

In the **`WebSecurityConfig`**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(environment), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/open-api/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("someUser")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("somePassword"))
                .authorities("ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**Controllers:**

**`AuthController`**

```
@RestController
public class AuthController implements EnvironmentAware {
    
    private Environment environment;

    @PostMapping("auth")
    public User login(@RequestParam("user") String name, @RequestParam("password") String pwd) {
        String token = getJWTToken(name);
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        user.setToken(token);       
        return user;
        
    }

    private String getJWTToken(String username) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = AuthorityUtils
                .commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
        String token = Jwts
                .builder()
                .setId("softtekJWT")
                .setSubject(username)
                .claim("authorities",
                        grantedAuthorities.stream()
                                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + Long.parseLong(environment.getProperty("millisecond.expiration"))))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512,
                        environment.getProperty("secret.key").getBytes()).compact();

        return "Bearer " + token;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(final Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

}
```

The **`UserController`**:

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityRequirement;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserServiceIface userService;
    
    @Autowired UserPasswordValidator userPasswordValidator;
    
    @Operation(summary = "list Users", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth"))
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> list(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userService.findAll());
    }

    @Operation(summary = "view User", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth"))
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> view(@PathVariable Long id) {
        
        Optional<User> optionalStoredUser = userService.findById(id);
        if (!optionalStoredUser.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(optionalStoredUser.get());
    }

    @Operation(summary = "create User", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth"))
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String token, 
            @Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult result) {
        
        userPasswordValidator.validate(user, result);
        throwExceptionIfErrors(result);
        
        Optional<User> optionalStoredUser = userService.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (optionalStoredUser.isPresent()) {
            throw new ExistingMailException(user.getEmail());
        }
        
        user.setIsactive(true);
        user.setToken(token);
        
        User createdUser = userService.save(user);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(createdUser);
    }

    @Operation(summary = "edit User", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth"))
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> edit(@RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String token, 
            @Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult result, @PathVariable Long id) {
        
        userPasswordValidator.validate(user, result);
        throwExceptionIfErrors(result);
        
        if (user.getEmail() != null && !user.getEmail().isEmpty()) {
            boolean emailUsed = userService.findByEmailAndIdNot(user.getEmail(), id).size() > 0;
            if (emailUsed) {
                throw new ExistingMailException(user.getEmail());
            }
        }
        
        Optional<User> optionalStoredUser = userService.findById(id);
        if (!optionalStoredUser.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        
        User editedUser = optionalStoredUser.get();
        editedUser.setName(user.getName());
        editedUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        editedUser.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        editedUser.setPhones(user.getPhones());
        editedUser.setModified(new Date());
        editedUser.setIsactive(user.isIsactive());
        editedUser.setToken(token);
        try {
            User updatedUser = userService.save(editedUser);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(updatedUser);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            throw new DefaultException(exp.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    @Operation(summary = "delete User", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth"))
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        userService.deleteById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
    
    private void throwExceptionIfErrors(BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            FieldError passwordFieldError = result.getAllErrors()
                    .stream().map(e -> (FieldError) e)
                    .filter(f -> f.getField().equals("password"))
                    .findFirst().orElse(null);
            
            if (passwordFieldError != null) {
                throw new PatternPasswordException(passwordFieldError.getDefaultMessage());
            }
            FieldError emailFieldError = result.getAllErrors()
                    .stream().map(e -> (FieldError) e)
                    .filter(f -> f.getField().equals("email"))
                    .findFirst().orElse(null);
            
            if (emailFieldError != null) {
                throw new PatternEmailException(emailFieldError.getDefaultMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my **`pom.xml`**

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.8.2</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.8.2</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.8.2</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
<!--            <version>4.2.0</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
<!--            <version>4.2.0</version> -->
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

Now **`UserControllerTest`** in the test:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;


@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    
    @MockBean
    private UserServiceIface userService;
    
    @MockBean
    UserPasswordValidator userPasswordValidator;
    
    private List<User> users;
    
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        users = new ArrayList<User>() {
            {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(1L);
                user.setName("First");
                user.setEmail("i@country.com");
                user.setPassword("abc1");
                add(user);
                user = new User();
                user.setId(2L);
                user.setName("Second");
                user.setEmail("you@country.com");
                user.setPassword("abc2");
                add(user);
                user = new User();
                user.setId(3L);
                user.setName("Third");
                user.setEmail("he@country.com");
                user.setPassword("abc3");
                add(user);
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    void testList() throws Exception {
        // given
        when(userService.findAll()).thenReturn(users);
        
        // then
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/users").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].name").value("First"))
        ;
    }
```

Running I get:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 403
    Error message = Access Denied
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

**EDIT 1:**

I changed my test class!

```
package org.bz.ms.app.usuarios.controllers;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserServiceIface userService;

    @MockBean
    UserPasswordValidator userPasswordValidator;

    private List<User> users;
    
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        
        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).apply(springSecurity()).build();
        
        // userDao = mock(UserDao.class); // Manually
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        users = new ArrayList<User>() {
            {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(1L);
                user.setName("First");
                user.setEmail("i@country.com");
                user.setPassword("abc1");
                add(user);
                user = new User();
                user.setId(2L);
                user.setName("Second");
                user.setEmail("you@country.com");
                user.setPassword("abc2");
                add(user);
                user = new User();
                user.setId(3L);
                user.setName("Third");
                user.setEmail("he@country.com");
                user.setPassword("abc3");
                add(user);
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    void testList() throws Exception {
        // given
        when(userService.findAll()).thenReturn(users);

        // then
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/users").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
        // .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        // .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].name").value("First"))
        ;
    }

}
```

I have doubts about this injection, but I think that I have: `WebSecurityConfig` and `OpenApi30Config`.

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;
```

and this on `setUp` method:

```
        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).apply(springSecurity()).build();
```

**How to test my controller including the security?**

Comment: So you enabled security, your test fails because you don't have a proper token in your request and you wonder why it fails?

Comment: @m-deinum its is first try, and I don't know how to pass the token in my test!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you configure the API can only be accessed by an authenticated user but now you are sending a request as an anonymous user and hence it return 403 access denied error.

The most simplest way is to add `@WithMockUser` to the test method. It will emulate the test are running with an authenticated user . It also allows to configure what the authorities or role do this user has :

```java
    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    void testList() throws Exception {
        // given
        when(userService.findAll()).thenReturn(users);
        
        // then
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/users").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].name").value("First"))
        ;
    }
```

Please note that `@WithMockUser` requires to add the `spring-security-test` dependency :

```xml
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: unfortunately I was reading how to implement the Security, but the tutorial not covers the tests! In my `pom.xml` is already the nedeed dependency. I put the annotation and I had the same error 403 code. I don't know how to pass the Token.